# Web browser with Java applet release native library

Tags: java, ubuntu, browser, applet, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a web page with multiple Java3D applets, running Firefox or Chromium on Ubuntu. I can start any one of the applets, but when I "go back" in the browser and try to start another Java3D applet, I get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:Native Library /lib/libj3dcore-ogl.so already loaded in another classloader
```

I can close the web browser and restart, and then I can start the other applet, but once again, trying to start another applet after that results in the above error.

Contrary to the web browser, I can run as many Java3D applets in Eclipse as I want. (Amazing-overlapping OpenGL windows in Java!)

Is there a way to run a Java3D applet in the browser after another has run without restarting the browser?

Note: I have a feeling that leaving a page does not mean that the applet is closed, but still running as far as the browser is concerned. Perhaps a Javascript that forces an applet to end when the page is left?

If you want to see the error, download the zip file from

http://jat.sourceforge.net/node/24

extract, and open index.html in deploy to run locally (The applets on the Internet don't run at all-not there yet). Then open one applet, go back, and try to run another 3D applet.

Answer (score 0):

Ufff, that's one of the worst errors of Java Security, the problem is simple, when you open the page your applet load the Native Library (i use Morena for Scan in Browser) then everything works fine, but when you refresh, your applet try to reload the Native Library, but the browser saves the applet in cache (that way it doesn't need to download again), then the Native is already loaded, generating a security issue, reason why you can't load a Native Resource twice (yes, your applet it does just one, but it's called each time the applet gets loaded, but the class loader only get created the first time).
You have no solution... MUAJAJAJAJA!, no, really, you can add your libs (the ones that uses native resources) and add them directly to your java/extensions, but the applet then would need some extra steps instead of just load the Applet.
I guess you already singed your jars, since it's neeeded for run native code in applet, but until today i'm unable to skip that refresh problem with applets that use Native, only adding them to extensions folder